# Sublime Text 3 Not compatible with current theme after update

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, sublimetext, macos-mojave

So I'm on Mac OS X Mojave, and saw this menu when I open my SBT3

[image]

When I click Download, open the app again, I kept getting this error stuck on looping.

[image]

I had to remove the latest one from the **Application** folder paste back my old from the Trash  to resume my previous state.

Does anyone else experience this also, and know how to by pass this ?

Comment: I also had errors with some packages after the update. Some automatic updates followed through package manager and the errors went away. Did you try to reinstall sublimelinter through package manager?

Comment: @kyo: When you cd into `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages` do you see `SublimeLinter/Monokai (SL).tmTheme`? I'm guessing that the path is set incorrectly for `"color_scheme"` in `Preferences.sublime-settings` (in the `User` directory), the theme is actually missing, or maybe something else altogether. Sometimes if you simply remove `"color_scheme"` from the preferences the issue resolves itself next time you launch Sublime Text.

Comment: The `(SL)` makes it looks suspiciously like a SublimeLinter auto-generated color scheme. This sort of thing could happen if the color scheme went away while it was in use; in that case, closing all open files and re-opening them may clear the error by implicitly resetting things. If this color scheme is set in your user preferences, I'd swap to another one.